# How message digest is considerd digital signature

Tags: web-services, security, https

In https protocol a per-secrect key is generated by client and is sent to server . And for thereon symmetric encryption takes place .My question is if this is the case how a message digest is considered as signed by server .

Or the digital signature comes to play only in establishing https connection ?. 
Does it apply only to public keys ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You skipped the most important part (in terms of trust) of the protocol.  The client (browser) needs to confirm that the server is who it claims to be.  The server provides to the client its certificate for this proof.  The client then does a number of checks on the certificate such as:

- Does it have a valid [chain of trust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_of_trust)?
- Is the root signature authority a trusted authority by the client?
- Is the certificate within its period of validity?
- Has the certificate been revoked?  (this check is not always possible)

And a few other checks.  Once the client trusts the certificate, it can then use it to establish a session with the the server using its public key.  The creation of the session involves sharing symmetric keys (note the plural) for the remaining communications.

During the session, two types of security are enforced: privacy via encryption and message integrity via MAC (typically HMAC).  The MAC is a symmetric method for computing signatures on every message using a shared secret key (one of the keys that was shared during the creation of the session).  This prevents a 3rd party from altering the messages in transit.

You ask how "message digest is considered digital signature?"  I think you are referring to the MAC part of the protocol in your question.  For more information, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code).

Comment: Sir could you please shed more light on situation where digital signatures are used .

Comment: Every certificate is digitally signed.  That certificate promises us that when we see https://example.com, we are really accessing example.com and not somewhere else.

Comment: So digital signature is part of certificate which is hash of private key of sender ? So how can digital signatures be used to verify integrity as well.The definition says digital signatures can be used to check integrity as well

Comment: "So digital signature is part of certificate" - yes.  "which is hash of private key of sender ?"  Huh?  No.  "So how can digital signatures be used to verify integrity as well."  Two meanings for integrity: (1) integrity of the sender (this is the person who it claims to be) which I answered above, (2) integrity of the message (this has not been modified in transit) - if message is modified, then signature won't check out.